# Elasticsearch javascript external script examples

Tags: javascript, load, elasticsearch, external

I started exploring scripts in elasticsearch a few days ago and since then I couldn't find a single example on net to see how the simplest things can be done. If anyone did this before, it would be really nice if he can post them here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe better if you share what you want to achieve. Would you be using the default mvel or some other scripting language?

Comment: Instead of writing script inside the query I would like to specify there only name to the file, and there to write complete script. Script should be in javascript and it should for example work as additional filter, or sorting, but I don't know how to send parameters to script, how to get them there and how to return them.

In fact it will be equally useful if there is any more complex example of script in js that is inside the query.

Comment: Is that at all possible? Never heard of that. Do you have a link where it's mentioned as a feature?

Comment: I found it here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/modules/scripting/

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to go through this tutorial:
https://www.sitepoint.com/building-recipe-search-site-angular-elasticsearch/
It describes in very good detail how you can use JavaScript along with elasticsearch to form your queries and do all that you mentioned.

Some of it might be deprecated so I'm gonna leave you with another link:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/index.html
This gives a really good description of the current JavaScript API which you can use for elasticsearch. I built a webpage which uses node.js and express for the web framework and uses the elasticsearch API to connect to the elasticsearch database while creating the frontend using AngularJS, HTML and CSS.